# Heroku App Crashed No Errors In Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi I am trying to deploy a small app on heroku

I managed to create the app, push the contents to the app, scaled it by one dyno but when I try to do heroku open, the app crashed and gave me error code 10

Here is the log file in paste bin

http://pastebin.com/Rh4iXn3Y

I found this error, uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
I uninstalled the simpleform gem but I figured it left behind some files that the gem didn't remove, I removed the file myself.

It should not throw me this error.

I am new to heroku, I know I need to dig through the doc to see how it works, but in the mean time can some one help me out?

thanks!
if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

From your log file:

```
2013-05-16T00:02:10.346211+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
```

Remove `/app/config/initializers/simple_form.rb`

Don't afraid of reading logs line by line. Near all answers are already there.

Comment: no I did remove the simple_form already but I am still getting this simple_form error? I pushed the app without simple_form to heroku

Comment: Hi @Jngai1297, as @Noma4i said, there something wrong in `/app/config/initializers/simple_form.rb`. Double check again and ensure you removed the wrong code and commit all modified ones to Heroku git.

Comment: If webserver is saying that it is stoping on this file it looks like you not pushed last changes. Ideally you need remove this file.